# Capitalize first word in each row of a column in mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to capitalize the first letter of every word in each row of a column.

So I create a new column, type in =PROPER(B2), then drag that down the entire length of that column. It works great, it displays column B with the proper capital letters.

So I want to get rid of the original column because I want to use the newly created column, when I do that, the new column only displays: #REF!

I know why it would do that, since I deleted the column it referred to, but how do I properly replace that column with the changes I made with =PROPER() without getting the #REF!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the fixed up cells. Then highlight the cells you want to replace and right-click to pop-up a menu. From the `Paste Options` section select `Values (V)`. This will just copy over the values and not the formulas.